# What are the disadvantages of CISC architecture?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

I took the computer architecture exam today. Our teacher asked a question.

> What are the disadvantages of CISC architecture ?

1. Increases the number of commands while writing the program
2. Makes pipelines difficult
3. Makes assembly code writing difficult for the programmer
4. Makes difficult compiler writing

You can choose multiple options. I chose 2 and 3.
Makes pipelines difficult and Makes assembly code writing difficult for the programmer

The results of exam says 2 and 4.
Makes pipelines difficult and Makes difficult compiler writing

I think the answer of teacher wrong because CISC has many complex instructions. It is beneficial for compilers. It makes compiler writing easy. CISC has many instructions it makes assembly code writing difficult for the programmer.

What do you guys think about this thing.

Comment: What does it say in your course materials? You have some reasonable answers below...your instructor is correct. The evidence of this is that RISC CPUs are gaining in popularity with respect to CISC processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a right or wrong thing, it is an opinion.  This is one of those things where you have a teacher or university program that has some opinion they want to convey, be it factual or not.  And the bottom line is you need to understand what they believe the answer is and put that on the test to pass the class, once you leave that test or that class or that university then you can seek out either the truth or opinions as the case may be.

The concept of CISC goes back to hand drawn masks and as a result human error and very high cost of creating silicon.  It may have been some great revelation or dumb luck or obvious that one would make an architecture that is built on busses and muxes and to make it work you put a state machine in the middle and use that to drive things....Using a rom or some such equivalent that can be changed later, microcode, so that you do not have to get all of the chip perfect, you leave room for it to be programmable, in the same way that we embed microcontrollers or fpgas or other field programmable items into designs today so that we do not have to re-call and re-spin a product we can fix/improve things in the field or in the production line with the hardware we have.

It did not have to happen this way but the CISC machines tended to do many steps per operation, addition between a memory item and a register, which means perform the memory operation to get that operand perform the register fetch to get that operand perform the add, then store the output in whichever memory is indicated, the register file or memory location with a memory cycle.  Rather than break that into a load from memory, perform the add in registers, store to memory.  All of those steps happen, but as one big instruction sequence rather than three separate.  The concept of RISC was to simplify the complexity of each instruction, avoiding the need for microcode, but also at a time when the tools were better, there was more experience with making chips, etc.  So the risk was a bit less in attempting perfection in the design and implementation, rather than leaving room for after the fact changes.

I do not see how it hurts pipelines, you can pipeline a CISC just as you can a RISC, esp if microcoded, because that is what can go through the pipe.  Even if not microcoded you are still doing the same elementary types of things once decoded.  and can pipeline those things.

I do not see how the assembly language is worse, x86 is a crappy instruction set, and that makes it difficult, has nothing to do with being CISC.  There are CISC instruction sets that are nice to write code for, and x86 has even gotten easier since the first days where the AX,BX,CX,DX registers had special purposes and you could not do anything with any register, some things could only be done with a specific register.

There are times where the line between the two has gotten a bit fuzzy.  I would leave CISC vs RISC and harvard vs von neumann in the text books where you left them, learn what the school wants to you to answer on the tests, do not try to be a hero and educate the school, just get your degree and leave.  Then enter the real world with the rest of us and finish your education, question everything you learned while at the same time using the things you learned to question it.

What you will find is you may walk into a job or career where they also have a strong opinion about something or are deeply integrated with some tool or process, and if you want to keep that job, at least for the first 20 years while you are not in charge, you learn the process and the opinion, and you do the job, even if you dont agree. (the grass is not greener when you go somewhere else it is just different grass).  You may find they use some ancient tools for an ancient processor that they have been using for a long time, and that does not mean it is bad business sense, they have a relationship with that company and a lot of experience with those tools and that product.  Vs trying something new and the cost of the change and the risk of a product line or many failing trying the new thing.  So this education is in part a life lesson in understanding that the world does not operate on best or proper or newest technology, or the coolest fad.  And while you have an opinion on what the company should do or try, you need to present it properly at the proper time, and usually that means 10-20+ years with the same company and same co-workers.  Not your first couple of years in.

We live in a time where you can easily go do things on your own, have a hobby that tries the new stuff, while doing it the company way to pay the bills.  It is called work for a reason, it is not called fun it is called work.

So the richness of the instruction set be it RISC or CISC makes the compilers job more difficult.  There are situations where it is a wash, CISC may have more options, register and memory and immediate operands, where RISC may only have register operands and to do a simple thing like add to numbers that are on the stack and put in a third location on the stack because the optimizer decided that is where these things should live, the RISC while easy is still work to have to put together a handful of instructions where CISC maybe one or two instructions depending, then it is an opinion as to which is "more difficult" sequencing more things more compiler code to break the problem down into smaller more atomic pieces, or being able to work at a higher, simpler level and place the CISC instructions? (in general more lines of code adds risk so if one solution takes more code it means more risk of the tool failing as well as more maintenance)  There is clearly no exact answer here it depends on the instruction set be it CISC or RISC as to how difficult or easy it is, how difficult or easy just the raw compiling of instructions and then ordering or reducing it to an optimal number of them based on optimization algorithms.  If you can find one easier CISC and one harder RISC, then it is a bogus argument.  And you can because you can easily create your own instruction sets for demonstration purposes.  Compilers are written by humans and are no more perfect than the humans that wrote them.  They are algorithm based so they are themselves not as advanced as those humans writing them they may not be able to get a particular program to compile into the most optimal code, algorithmically, it is quite common that you can "improve" the output of a compiler as a result by hand tuning.

Pipelines are just assembly lines, you look at the problem to be solved and you break it down into steps that make sense then you order the steps in a way that makes sense, you parallelize as needed (paint takes time to dry so many car doors and chassis need to go through in parallel so that one is dry and ready every so many minutes, but doors may only take a minute each to hang so you do not need width there, one station will do.  Designing a pipeline is no different.  RISC in cases has less variation on the length of instructions vs CISC if you look at the popular ones, 6502, x86, etc vs mips/arm (which are variable length as well but not as severe) and just fetching and decoding is a bottleneck with CISC more so than RISC if you generalize them into those few examples.

There are real world differences between specific RISC and CISC processors, but still be careful not to generalize.  What you should do in general is when you leave school not look at the world as CISC vs RISC and harvard vs von neumann (embedded, real-time, system on a chip, ...), because the reality is there is not this purity in the world, the lines between things are a bit fuzzy.  Worse, the vocabulary is not exact, and never expect it to be exact that will simply drive you crazy, each company, each team has their own dictionary if you will for common terms and you learn the language when you get there, learn to translate to what you think in your head for those terms.  Nobody is wrong these terms are soft and fuzzy anyway so just roll with it rather than try to define things with rigid terms and absolutes.  Learn to translate to the language of the person listening to you rather than force them to learn your language and how you use terms.  What will come with time is that between you you will create a language together of terms that you use and their definitions.

That is how the real world works.  How the school world works, is that the professors answers are right and if you cannot guest the professors answers then you are wrong.  Some mind reading is required as there have been large volumes of bad exam and homework questions posted to sites like this.  My usual recommendation is find a different (better) teacher or school, but obviously that is not an option for most people.  The more likely choice is just put what the teacher wanted and do not argue or make waves as that may affect your ability to graduate.  Yes sir, yes ma'am and move on with your life.

Comment: Sir thank you for your comments.

Comment: Disagree. In the context of 1980s computer architecture, these points are not merely opinion. RISC processors were designed to be easy to pipeline *on limited density logic processes of that era* and if that meant they were harder to program, then so be it.  Since RISC/CISC hasn't been meaningful in 25 years, these points seem strange and irrelevant when applied to modern processors, but in terms of understanding why we design processors the way we do they're still helpful conceptually even if you can now pipeline anything given 10 billion transistors per die.

Comment: @user1850479 The question isn't whether it is **possible** to "pipeline anything" but whether doing so is a good use of those billions of transistors. I think the proof of the pudding is that chip architects are trending toward RISC.

Comment: you can build your cisc out of risc or other things that are easy to pipeline, that is basically the basis of cisc, turn the instruction into a series of simple steps, easily pipelined.  cisc isnt any harder to pipeline than risc.  architects are not necessarily trending toward risc because of the word risc, they are trending toward isas that put more burden on the programmer and tools than on the logic, because we have much better tools today than we did way back when.  we have more ram to burn, etc.

Comment: which has also played a major role in how we design the chips and what we can expect to produce how many spins, etc.  because the tools are so much better now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to user1850479's answer, the RISC concept not only means to reduce the number of different instructions, but to make the instruction set very regular, without the special cases that you find in typical CISC processors (some operations only possible on some registers, some supporting memory access, some only registers, and so on).

A regular instruction set makes it easier for a compiler to produce good code. E.g. if all registers are treated equal, there's no need to reason about the best register for some value, the compiler can just use any available one.

Compare that to an example CISC processor with a very efficient block copy instruction, but needing source address, destination address and count in specific registers. For a compiler to make best use of that instruction, it needs to know in advance that such a block copy is expected, and arrange the values in the appropriate registers in advance, thus needing quite some look-ahead when deciding on register assignment.

on the other hand, the typical assembly programmer will be happy about such an instruction, saving him from having to write a memory-copy subroutine.

So, in general I agree with the "official" answers, although that is opinion-based to some degree. For the human programmer, CISC has a steeper learning curve until you master all the special instructions, but to the experienced programmer, it then makes things easier. RISC is easier to learn, but you lack the special instructions that make life easier - you have to write boringly lengthy instruction sequences for things that a CISC machine can do in one line.

Answer (score 2):

CISC is a compromise which gives more complex and powerful instructions that do more stuff thus you need less instructions, which makes code smaller... at the cost of making the processor hardware more complicated and expensive, because it has to decode and execute more types of instructions.

> Increases the number of commands while writing the program

If that means "CISC requires more instructions to do the same stuff" then no, it's the opposite. RISC usually requires more instructions because each instruction do less stuff.

> Makes pipelines difficult

That's one side-effect of making the hardware more complicated, so yes. One big reason why RISC is so popular is that it's simpler and the hardware is easier to optimize for speed and low power. Essentially a CISC processor is a RISC processor with a built-in interpreter which translates machine code into simpler instructions for the "real" cpu inside. On a RISC chip this is done by the software compiler, which saves money and power.

> Makes assembly code writing difficult for the programmer

That depends: it'll be easier to memorize the lower number of instructions of a RISC processor, but you'll have to write more of them. So it's a draw. Back then when I was writing assembly I found the difficulty was more related to quirks, special restrictions, non-general purpose registers that must be used to do some specific stuff, etc. For example a RISC with 16 general purpose registers will be a lot simpler than an old CISC which can only perform arithmetic on the accumulator, or an old rustbucket microcontroller which only has registers A and B... Likewise for restrictions like "this addressing mode is only available for this instruction" or stuff like that. How flags work, how conditional jumps work, etc.

> Makes difficult compiler writing

If the goal is an optimizing compiler that produces fast code, then the compiler must be able to predict how many cycles each instruction takes, what the latencies and dependencies are, etc, in order to pick the best instructions and also reorder instructions for maximum performance. CISC makes this a lot more opaque, so I'd answer "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Writing programs using only very simple operations is difficult because it forces you to build the operation you want out of multiple more simple operations. The reason we have programing languages is to aggregate simple operations into more complex ones that are easier to work with. In principle, an architecture that provides you with more powerful operations could be easier to program than one that provides you with only the absolute minimum.

For example, pure RISC system might force you to load a value, perform an operation on it and then write back. Classic CISC systems would often have single instructions that could load, add and sometimes even write back. This is much less work.

In practice real RISC processors tend to not be all that simple, and real CISC processors tend not to be all that easy to program, but for an basic question it's reasonable enough.

Comment: So my answer is correct and teacher's answer is wrong.

Comment: @EnverPasha Hmmm, I think CISC actually makes writing the compiler more difficult because you have to decide when to use the complex instructions and when not to. I think it is trickier to optimize CISC as well. Being longer is not always the same as being more difficult. But this question has a lot of grey area.

Comment: @DKNguyen if you look like that it is true but you have complex instructions. For example you have multiply as a instruction in CISC but you dont have multiply instruction RISC. To perform a multiplication operation in RISC you need to write several instructions. But CISC supplies this in one instruction.

Comment: @EnverPasha As I said, length is not the same as difficulty.

Comment: @Mat Certainly not, but OP is specifically talking about *writing* the compiler

Comment: @EnverPasha If you look at the ISA of even a tiny Cortex-M3 you will find built-in multiply instructions as single assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to match the available instructions against the desired behaviour of the program.

The program is compiled down to an abstract level first, which uses an infinite number of registers and abstract descriptions of operations. For these abstract operations, we want to avoid redundancy in the opcode set, because that would create ambiguity.

For example, if the available operations are "subtract", "compare" and "compare against zero", then `(a == b)` could be represented as either `(compare0 (subtract a b))` or as `(compare a b)`, so we remove "compare" from the abstract set to get an unambiguous intermediate representation.

If the CPU now offers an instruction that implements direct comparison between two values, then during instruction generation we need to match subtrees against `(compare0 (subtract ... ...))` to find instances where it is possible to use the comparison operation. If the CPU also offers a "test" instruction that compares against zero, we get two possible ways of encoding `(compare0 (subtract a b))` -- as `"sub" a b -> c; "test" c -> p` or as `"cmp" a b -> p`.

Now if we also need `a - b` at another point of the program, we might have an instance of `c = (subtract a b)` in the intermediate representation somewhere, giving the Common Subexpression Elimination pass the option to replace `p = (compare a b)` with `p = (compare0 c)`.

This gives us better code if the register allocator can save the contents of `c` between the two places, and worse code if it can't, so we need to keep both options in the tree, and do lifetime analyses for `a`, `b` and the `c` intermediate for both cases, and see which solution is better in order to generate optimal code. Having to choose between "compare" and "test for zero" opcodes already adds this complexity, so adding more opcodes that do subtly different things and have different execution time and constraints around their use makes this a lot more complex to do efficiently.

In contrast, assembler programmers don't usually optimize for best execution time, but towards a program that can be understood and maintained. Explicitly comparing `a` to `b` is clearer than subtracting and testing for zero, and it means not using a register for a temporary, which means we might get away with not saving data to the stack.